# Understanding residence question in UK Visa application

Tags: visas, uk

When applying for a UK visa one question asks:

> What is your usual country of residence?

What does that mean? "Usual" seems like a particularly bad and ambiguous word choice here. Do I give the country that has been my country of residence for the longest time or the most recent one (or yet something else)?

---

I will just add that I don't think it is useful to point out that often the answer to this question will be clear cut and that many different criteria give the same answer. If someone is coming to this question there are clearly multiple at least somewhat reasonable answers. The question is about which criteria to use to select the correct one. Or an equally valid answer would be that all somewhat reasonable answers are correct and none of them will lead to trouble. If the latter is true of course. (It would also be great to have some evidence backing up any answer.)

Comment: Not a duplicate, but very related: [How is the "country of habitual residence" defined?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/181629/how-is-the-country-of-habitual-residence-defined)

Comment: I'll suggest that phoog's answer to the question cited in Greg Hewgill's comment is very relevant to your situation. They conclude — and I agree — that focusing on facts rather than on words would be more productive enquiry.

Comment: How can one focus on facts rather than words? The form does not allow me to explain my situation. It allows me just to enter one country. So unfortunately the interpretation will have to be made by me (at least at this point in the process). (It might be irrelevant which interpretation I make, and if you have good evidence for this that would of course be an acceptable answer).

Comment: Phoog's point in the cited question is that the UK visa authorities don't define "usual." Thus, you've left open the possibility that your application will be assessed based on your country of citizenship, and/or the identities of the various other countries where you've lived, and/or the duration of those other country residences, and the reasons you were there. Without a UK definition of "usual," or your statement of the missing factors above, no one here can say more than "consult a dictionary."

Comment: For most people the answer would be the same as if they were asked in ordinary conversation, "where do you live?" For some people the answer would be where they have been legally resident for most of the past year. If you're an edge case who moves from country to country every few weeks then where is your legal or registered residence or what is the country that issued your passport?

Comment: Sorry Kate you are confusing residency with Citizenship or something similar. You must reside or still be with in the period of time for which you have already qualified to be a resident. Once outside of this window you will be non resident within a country. Therefore you cannot be usually resident of somewhere you lived most of your life if you no longer live there. The expression “usually resident is not ambiguous in regard to past residency etc as it is defined by most governments

Comment: https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/networks/european-migration-network-emn/emn-asylum-and-migration-glossary/glossary/usual-residence_en. However the details for qualification may vary from country to country.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is the place you consider your current home, i.e. the place you spend most of the time in the year, most likely the only place you are a tax resident of.

It’s “usual” in terms of “if you stay 10 months of the year in country A and 2 months in country B for holidays”, then it’s A, not B even if right now at this precise moment you are in B.

It’s not usual as in over many years. Even if you spent 65 years of your life in country A, if now you live in country B, then the answer is B.

This is the place you would normally have a place to live, where your family (spouse, children) live.

In most cases it would be the place where you work and have a bank account, though there are exceptions for both.

Comment: This is definitely the clearest answer. That would be one way that the usage of the word "usual" would make sense. I guess I will accept it. Although it contains no source confirming this and is not 100% in agreement with the other answer. It feels a bit like I am just guessing that your answer is the most accurate interpretation of the question.

Comment: I don't think the part about spouse and children is that clarifying by the way. More confusing. How can that be the criteria when you just said something else is. And if you are just saying most peoples families happen to live in their current country of residency than that seems like a weird unrelated fact to mention that can only serve to further confuse things. (If they live in a different country than me, would this affect anything for example? I think you are saying no, so why include it in the answer?)

Comment: As you may have noted, there are lots of “normallys” and “usuallys” and “likelys”. For most people the answer is clear-cut, then there are lots of special cases, like people not living with their family, people commuting between two countries on a daily basis (sleeping at home every night), on a weekly basis (weekdays in work country, weekends with family), and so on. If you have a specific case in mind you can post that as a new question, I was trying to describe the most common cases to keep it simple.

Comment: Well I was just commenting that I think that one sentence has no clarifying value. I was also asking some questions about your intent because perhaps you did mean it to have meaning. At the moment is kind of like saying "it is usually where you keep your playstation". It might be. Or it might not. But it has no bearing on the question. If it does have bearing I would explain it. If it does not I would remove it.

Answer (score 5):

I doubt there is a hard and simple rule here. If you lived in Country A for 50 years, and then moved to Country B where you lived for 20 years, I don't think you'd like it if someone said Country B wasn't your usual country of residence just because you hadn't caught up to the time you spent in Country A yet. But if you own a house and have a pet and such in one country and just landed in a second country this morning, I would not believe you when you claimed your usual residence was that second country.

I would ask you questions like these:

- do you own a place to live (house, apartment etc)? Where?
- do you have a job that requires you to be at a workplace or are you a student who needs to attend class? Where?
- where are the majority of your possessions?

For most people, the answers to these are all the same place, even if it's a place they've only recently moved to. But a lot of this depends on your personal feelings. You may feel that Country C is home and where you usually live, even if you are in Country D for work or school for a few years. You can probably defend almost any answer to this question. There may exist a weird edge case person who is a citizen of E, lived in F for decades, owns property in G, sleeps each night in H, works most days in I, and has a strong attachment to J even though they only get there a few times a year. What's their usual country of residence? They might be able to claim any of those, depending on how they feel about it.

We have seen some questions here from people who can't get visas because they don't have enough status in their country of habitual residence. So it might be advantageous to say your country of usual residence is one where you're a citizen, if that's a true claim to be making.

Comment: (+1) For the purposes of a visa application, to claim a country as your ‘usual residence’ it would also be necessary to be *lawfully residing* there under any relevant legislation or rules which apply in that country.

Comment: Very good point to make that for some people there may be multiple reasonable answers, and it's up to the applicant to choose whichever is most advantageous to them. As long as the answer is reasonable, there's no issue choosing the answer that benefits you most in making the application.

Comment: @MJeffryes, that would be a great answer if true. Is it true? Can an application be disapproved because the applicant interpreted "usual country of residency" in a way the immigration office doesn't agree with?

Comment: To make it clear that questions such as the above don't fully clarify which country I should answer. My answers are: I don't own, I rent in say country A. I have a job country A but obviously my employement in my current country will end because I will be moving and working in the UK after my successful visa application. And again my majority of possesions are in one country (to be moved to the UK). Three years before this the answer to all questions was Country B. Four years before that it was country C which is my country of origin.

Comment: I'm inclined to answer Country C as my usual country of residence since it is the country I have the closest ties with (despite not having lived there for the last 7 years).

Comment: @Kvothe *Can an application be disapproved because the applicant interpreted "usual country of residency" in a way the immigration office doesn't agree with?* Very generally speaking (and this strays into off topic because you seem to be asking about a UK residence, not visit visa) visas can only be refused for concrete failure to meet requirements *or* deception/lying. It would not be reasonable to accuse you of lying when you have a reasonable justification for claiming a particular country as residence.

Comment: the question says "is" not "will be" so your "after I get the visa the answer will be different" logic does not apply. You can probably defend either A or C, seven years isn't a **really** long time, but I would say A in your case especially if you have residency there.

Comment: @Kvothe You’re over-thinking this. To my mind, the answer is *country A*, where you’ve lived and worked for the last 3 years. IMHO saying that your habitual residence is a country where you haven’t lived or worked for 7 years makes little sense from an immigrant visa application point of view.

Comment: @Kate Gregory Your post is incorrect https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/networks/european-migration-network-emn/emn-asylum-and-migration-glossary/glossary/usual-residence_en. However the details for qualification may vary from country to country.

Comment: @Brad How can the EU website you cite in your comment affect the OP's visa application **to the UK**? The UK is not an EU member.

Answer (score 1):

Where is your main residence and where are you registered to pay tax. Normally these will be one and the same and is the answer they are looking for.

[Details for qualification as a resident may vary slightly from country to country.](https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/networks/european-migration-network-emn/emn-asylum-and-migration-glossary/glossary/usual-residence_en)

Please note
THERE IS A DIFFRENCE BETWEEN RRESIDENT AND CITIZENSHIP, also

1.Renting or owning a house is not relevant. Where you reside is the relevant factor.

2.The country of registration of your company or employers company is not relevant to you being a resident but it may be relevant to the qualification for residency.

3.What you posses or where those possesion are is not relevant to your place of residence. It may be relevant to citizenship but not residency.

4.You cannot be a resident until you have lived in a country for a defined period of time, so the fact you may be relocating is not relevant at this time.

5.Your country of origin or places of previous abode are irrelevant unless you meet the requirements of being a domiciled resident at the current time.

Comment: Do you have anything to back this up? How long should a country have been your current main residence and tax residency to be your "usual country of residency". You would argue instantly or at least if you have filed tax at least once?

Comment: It is common knowledge that every country has it's own laws. Therefore your request. I will assume it is a request ? (actually it sounds more like an accusation at best and a confrontation at worst) would be a country specific answer but the choices of possible places of residence are not provided. Here you can find the requirements for the UK https://www.gov.uk/tax-foreign-income/residence

Comment: This is a question about what the UK means with "usual country of residency" so it would be their laws and interpretations of them that would matter. Not of the country I reside in. I don't think this is an accusation. Any answer should ideally have a source to back it up. Note that your answer is not 100% compatible with other answers. How would I know your answer is correct and should be preferred over others if you are not including any source or evidence?

Answer (score 0):

It is where you reside usually.
Some theoretical discussions can be found at e.g. [Canadian government's report on residence in Canadian family law context](https://www.justice.gc.ca/eng/rp-pr/fl-lf/divorce/rhro_cl/p2.html#a2), but in the end you should not overthink it and interpret it "ordinarily" (which is what the government expects from you).

It is in the present tense, the first qualification has to be somewhere you can still be considered to be a resident of. An immigrant who just landed in Canada for permanent residence can claim Canada as their usual residence on the day of their landing and cannot claim their country of origin if they have no intention of returning to their country of origin any time soon (no, it is not well defined, but it does not matter for most people; for the judge, it will be I know it when I see it.).

The modifiers "usual", "habitual", "ordinary" serve to reduce the choices when your current residence may be exceptional. A worker in an offshore oil platform would claim where they *usually* reside onshore as their residence. An edge case could be when the worker stays at hotels or other short term residence providers in different countries while off work, then the worker has to decide on one and be prepared to justify his claim.

However, the usual residence does not have to be an exclusive concept (unlike domicile).
It is likely that frontier worker in Switzerland who only lives in France on the weekends (due to Swiss legal requirements) can reasonably claim both Switzerland and France as their ordinary residence (but only France as their domicile) under common law. Similarly, a detached worker or diplomats on assignment may claim multiple countries of "usual" residence.

An exchange student likely does not claim their current country of study as usual residence, whereas a student taking a degree program with longer duration
may be able to claim both country of study and the country where their family reside or where they have right of abode as their usual residence.

> To make it clear that questions such as the above don't fully clarify which country I should answer. My answers are: I don't own, I rent in say country A. I have a job country A but obviously my employement in my current country will end because I will be moving and working in the UK after my successful visa application. And again my majority of possesions are in one country (to be moved to the UK). Three years before this the answer to all questions was Country B. Four years before that it was country C which is my country of origin.

In your situation, country A is mostly likely your current usual residence. The concept of residence does not depend on past actions or future intent; except with the modifier "usual" exceptions exist if you do not consider your current situation usual. Country A is where you currently live, eat and sleep.

> Country C as my usual country of residence since it is the country I have the closest ties with (despite not having lived there for the last 7 years).

While country C is not necessarily disqualified from your usual country of residence, it is hard to justify. 7 years is a long time; if you obtained a PhD during that time, you may still be able to justify country C as where you would usually reside except for your pursuit of studies; similarly you may be able to justify the claim if you are sent overseas by an employer or the government in country C.

If you have been in country A in 7 years, claiming country A would also usually help with your application (not necessarily in the case of UK today), since a significant part of your recent personal history is in A, and you would get better treatment if your file is processed by an office familiar with conditions and documents in A.