# Retrying visa application with a different intent

Tags: visas, canada, russian-citizens

A corporate event is upcoming and all the employees are supposed to attend, but a few month ago my application for a tourist visa was rejected due to "The purpose of your visit to Canada is not consistent with a temporary stay", and now I wonder - should I retry a new application with this different intent and reasonably expect any different outcome, or it would be just a waste of time and money?

Comment: Ask also your company. There will be some person (not in your team) which know the things and can help. I doubt you are the only foreign employee (and for taxation an regulation, probably they got some guidelines). Try to get as much support as you can (considering previous rejection).

Comment: Is your company based in Russia or are your colleagues also Russian?

Comment: @jcaron it's based in the US, but our team mostly works with people in Canada.

Comment: And you are a Russian citizen with a work visa in the US, you're not coming from Russia, are you? Just wondering if they are just not afraid you could be trying to claim asylum or something similar. Or is there another reason for the rejection? I think the main issue is to understand the reasoning behind that rejection, to see if the corporate event reason is enough to compensate for the reason of the previous rejection or not.

Comment: @jcaron nope this branch where I currently work is in Mexico. TBH I'm not even trying to understand what the bureaucrats are thinking. Most likely they just don't.

Comment: @user626528 the average bureaucrat hates your guts (and everyone else's), but not consciously

Comment: @user253751: The average bureaucrat — hell, the average person anywhere — is mostly aiming to get through their day and keep their paychecks coming. Benevolence and malice alike are usually far secondary motivations.

Comment: @PLL and the way they get through their day is by acting as unfeeling agents of a machine that is mostly malevolent

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Yes**, it's a materially different reason to go, so it's definitely worth a shot.
This assumes your company is headquartered or otherwise has a significant operation in Canada, generally reputable (many local employees etc) and can provide a letter of invitation that:

- confirms you are employed by them outside Canada
- describes the event (exact dates, number of attendees) and that all employees are invited
- states that they will cover all your travel expenses

If your company is large enough to have immigration support, I would strongly encourage you to go through them to get the letter and if possible the visa itself.

Comment: "confirms you are employed by them outside Canada" - they did have this letter before, though.

Comment: The difference is that previously as a tourist they would have less of a reason to think "because of my job I will return". But when your employer is paying for the trip the connection is bigger.

Comment: It was too late for this event, but I'll try it next time.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact to be honest I still don't understand what difference this could make, because I have more than enough funds to pay for any trips.

Comment: @user626528 They're more concerned that you intend to move to Canada permanently.  This is literally what your previous denial reason, "not consistent with a temporary stay", means.

Comment: @lambshaanxy I don't see how the company paying for my trip is related to this.

Comment: @user626528 You have already had all of this explained to you in excruciating detail at your previous question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/179942/canadian-tourist-visa-refused-due-to-lack-of-family-ties-to-and-immigration-stat

Comment: @lambshaanxy well can you point at the explanation why the company paying for the trip changes anything?

Comment: @user626528 Your tourist visa was rejected because they did not think you were a genuine tourist.  But if an actual Canadian business invites you over for a  business trip, you have a much stronger case for a business visa.  The fact that the company is paying for your trip mainly demonstrates that the company is genuine about wanting you to visit and this is a "real" business trip.

Comment: @lambshaanxy ok this makes more sense.